# Bash script producing "syntax error near unexpected token 'done'"

Tags: bash, shell-script, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The shell script looks like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
while [ true ]; do
    clear
    date
    who
    sleep 5
done
```

If I run int, I get the following:

```
yuikus@DESKTOP-VTJ0OG4:~$ cd /mnt/d/lab_oc_1/lab_oc_2/
yuikus@DESKTOP-VTJ0OG4:/mnt/d/lab_oc_1/lab_oc_2/$ sh bag.sh
bag.sh: 7: Syntax error: "done" unexpected (expecting "do")
yuikus@DESKTOP-VTJ0OG4:/mnt/d/lab_oc_1/lab_oc_2/$ bash bag.sh
bag.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
bag.sh: line 7: `done '
```

Why doesn't it work? I run with Ubuntu, from Windows.

Comment: Also note that `[ true ]` is the same as `[ false ]`, i.e. it checks that the string isn't empty.

Comment: Try `watch -n 5 who`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas how do I write this down? what should be on which line? I'm really not good at this, I'm sorry

Comment: The `watch -n 5 who`  command should do what your script does

Comment: Please keep your question to one item at a time. I wrote my suggestion as an answer, in order to have the original problem "solved" (which you may want to [accept](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) if that actually was the solution). If you have a follow-up question, please don't modify the original question, but create a new onw. You can still add a link to this question to establish context.

Comment: @AdminBee Thank you so much for helping. one fast question How can i wrtite this symbol " | " in command line ? :)

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Do you mean which keys to press in order to create it? ... although since you just produced it in your comment, I doubt that this is the problem ...

Comment: @AdminBee I just inserted it using ctrl+c but i can't use it on command line :''')

Comment: Well, it strongly depends on your keyboard layout.

Comment: @AdminBee okay, fine does сtrl+c exist in the command line? :''''''''''''''''')

Comment: On your problem: What is the yout put of `bash -x bag.sh`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are operating Ubuntu under Windows, you likely edited the script concurrently with Windows and Linux editors. However, Windows and Linux use different line-endings, which can confuse script interpreters.

Run `dos2unix` over your script file; this will replace any Windows (CR-LF) line endings with Unix line endings:

```
$ dos2unix bag.sh
```

Then, run your script as originally intended. Note that since you have a `#!`-line stating `/bin/bash`, it would make more sense to make the script executable and run it as

```
$ ./bag.sh
```

than running it under `sh`, which may use another shell than the one you want (Bash).